# A word for something bad that is beautiful

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for something that is bad, sad or tragic, but is also beautiful in some way. Or the ABILITY to see beauty in such circumstances?

Comment: Could you provide an example of such 'something', please?

Comment: for example a fire or a volcano can be beautiful even though it has the ability to destroy or even kill people.
OR Romeo and Juliet is a tragedy but it's also beautiful

Comment: I've seen expressions such as 'the terrifying beauty of Vesuvius erupting'. Or you could talk about the *poignant beauty of the scene* - perhaps? But I shall be interested in other suggestions.

Comment: The phrase *tragic beauty* suggested in your question seems to capture it.

Comment: Its not perfect, and a jaoanese loan phrase but: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_no_aware

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that [bittersweet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bittersweet) is the word that you have in mind?

> Arousing pleasure tinged with sadness or pain: bittersweet memories of
>   his time in London